# conserve the some height for two bloc (dynamic row) with html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I would like to conserve the some height for two dynamic table.
I know that the solution is by using javascipt(
document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = document.getElementById('bloc1').clientHeight ).

Can we find other solution with the using of HTML and CSS?

Comment: Maybe, so if you start with posting the code you have that should behave like that and we'll try help you out

Comment: <div id="bloc1" >
        <table><thead>
          </thead><tbody>         
          <tr>
           <td><span>Sam</span></td>
           <td><span>23</span></td>
          </tr>   
     </tbody></table>
</div>  
<div id="bloc2">
        <table class="table-result-box-widget">
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>         
          <td><span>Sam</span></td>
           <td><span>23</span></td>
     <td><span>masculin</span></td>
           <td><span>work at bank</span></td>
     <td><span>traval</span></td>     
          </tr>   
</tbody></table>
</div>

Comment: Edit the code into your question, do not post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make an effort with your language skills (if you're not good at English, *verify it*), and use the styling tools of StackOverflow.

All the information is here, **check it out**. And as an answer I'd first advise not to use `<table>` if not really needed !

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="block_1" class="foo">
        <!-- Your HTML/text content -->
    </div>
    <div id="block_2" class="foo">
        <!-- Your HTML/text content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And for CSS (the values are examples, use yours) :

```
#container {
    width: 100%;

    /* The height will be minimum 350px, depending on the content */
    min-height: 350px;

    /* I often use flexbox properties, it does really well the job */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center; // Default value
}

.foo {
    width: 50%;
    /* this value will make your 2 blocks the same height according to their container */
    height: inherit;
}
```

Check the Flexbox properties (there are many), it can ease your work.

Comment: thank's for your answer, but the solution consiste to have two blox in the some line.

Comment: @rachedbch you are right. I edited my answer, now it should be good.